# How to parse/extract data from a mediawiki marked-up article via python

Tags: python, api, parsing, mediawiki, extract

[Source Mediawiki markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Foobar&redirects&rvprop=content&format=xml)

Right now I'm using a variety of regexes to "parse" the data in the mediawiki mark-up into lists/dictionaries, so that elements within the article can be used.

This is hardly the best method, as the number of cases that have to be made are large.

How would one parse an article's mediawiki markup into a variety of python objects so that the data within can be used?

Example being:

- Extract all headlines to a
  dictionary, hashing it with its
  section.
- Grab all interwiki links, and
  stick them into a list (I know
  this can be done from the API but I'd
  rather only have one API call to
  reduce bandwidth use).
- Extract all image names and hash them with
  their sections

A variety of regexes can achieve the above, but I'm finding the number I have to make rather large.

Here's the [mediawiki unofficial specification](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting) (I don't find their official [specification](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Markup_spec) as useful).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### mwlib - MediaWiki parser and utility library

[pediapress/mwlib](https://github.com/pediapress/mwlib):

> mwlib provides a library for parsing MediaWiki articles and converting them to different output formats. mwlib is used by wikipedia's "Print/export" feature in order to generate PDF documents from wikipedia articles.

Here's the [documentation](http://mwlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basics.html) page. The older doc page used have a one-liner example:

```
from mwlib.uparser import simpleparse
simpleparse("=h1=\n*item 1\n*item2\n==h2==\nsome [[Link|caption]] there\n")
```

If you want to see how it's used in action, see the test cases that come with the code. ([mwlib/tests/test_parser.py from git repository](https://github.com/pediapress/mwlib/blob/c41330f95e0e780026159ae95402b6d00511e05c/tests/test_parser.py)):

```
from mwlib import parser, expander, uparser
from mwlib.expander import DictDB
from mwlib.xfail import xfail
from mwlib.dummydb import DummyDB
from mwlib.refine import util, core

parse = uparser.simpleparse

def test_headings():
    r=parse(u"""
= 1 =
== 2 ==
= 3 =
""")

    sections = [x.children[0].asText().strip() for x in r.children if isinstance(x, parser.Section)]
    assert sections == [u"1", u"3"]
```

Also see [Markup spec](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Markup_spec) and [Alternative parsers](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) for more information.

Comment: I've looked at mwlib before. Can't seem to find some snippets of it actually in use though, which is the main problem. I'd appreciate any links to tutorials/examples.

Comment: They seem to have moved to github, could you please updte your links to: https://github.com/pediapress/mwlib

Comment: This examples parses article links out of a string of wikipedia text: https://gist.github.com/akellehe/65a040b53456d7d23544

Comment: Wikipedia has a list of parsers at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers which includes multiple Python offerings.

Answer (score 4):

This question is old, but for others coming here: There is a [mediawiki parser written in Python on github](https://github.com/erikrose/mediawiki-parser). It seems very easy to transform articles into pure plain text, something I, if I remember correctly, couldn't solve in the past with mwlib.

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for simillar solution to parse certain wiki , and stumbled upon [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) which takes multiple input formats and generates multiple too.

From the site:

> Pandoc - a universal document converter
>
> If you need to convert files from one markup format into another, pandoc is your swiss-army knife. Pandoc can convert documents in markdown, reStructuredText, textile, HTML, DocBook, LaTeX, MediaWiki markup, TWiki markup, OPML, Emacs Org-Mode, Txt2Tags, Microsoft Word docx, EPUB, or Haddock markup to
> HTML formats: XHTML, HTML5, and HTML slide shows using Slidy, reveal.js, Slideous, S5, or DZSlides.
> Word processor formats: Microsoft Word docx, OpenOffice/LibreOffice ODT, OpenDocument XML
> Ebooks: EPUB version 2 or 3, FictionBook2
> Documentation formats: DocBook, GNU TexInfo, Groff man pages, Haddock markup
> Page layout formats: InDesign ICML
> Outline formats: OPML
> TeX formats: LaTeX, ConTeXt, LaTeX Beamer slides
> PDF via LaTeX
> Lightweight markup formats: Markdown (including CommonMark), reStructuredText, AsciiDoc, MediaWiki markup, DokuWiki markup, Emacs Org-Mode, Textile
> Custom formats: custom writers can be written in lua.