# Extracting the introduction part of a Wikipedia article, by python

Tags: python, html-content-extraction

I want to extract the introduction part of a wikipedia article(ignoring all other stuff, including tables, images and other parts). I looked at html source of the articles, but I don't see any special tag which this part is wrapped in.

Can anyone give me a quick solution to this? I'm writing python scripts.

thanks

Comment: You probably want to be parsing the wiki markup, not the HTML, for this particular operation.

Comment: can you give more details? I'm not familiar with accessing wiki markup? How should I get it? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can often get to the intro text by taking the full page, stripping out all the tables, and then looking for the first sequence of <p>...</p> blocks after the  marker. That last bit would be this regex:

```
/<!-- bodytext -->.*?(<p>.*?<\/p>\s*)+/
```

With the .S option to make . match newlines...

Comment: No, but they're an expedient way when the needs are simple. But if you want to provide a specific HTML-library answer that's more helpful than my regex one, go right ahead.

Comment: Well, what's wrong with Beautiful Soup?  That would be more expedient than implementing your own ad-hoc parser that's incomplete and riddled with bugs.

Comment: I mean, provide an answer that shows how to use Beautiful Soup to get the intro sections out of Wikipedia pages, like the questioner wants. If you're right that it's more expedient, then that should be simple and your answer should be clearly better than mine.

Answer (score 3):

1. You may want to check **[mwlib](http://code.pediapress.com/wiki/wiki)** to parse the wikipedia source
2. Alternatively, use the [wikidump](https://github.com/saffsd/wikidump) lib
3. HTML screen scraping through [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Ah, there is a question already on SO on this topic:

1. [Parsing a Wikipedia dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463447/parsing-a-wikipedia-dump)
2. [How to parse/extract data from a mediawiki marked-up article via python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968132/how-to-parse-extract-data-from-a-mediawiki-marked-up-article-via-python)